# Json deserialization using java enums

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, enums, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize the following `JSON` to a java object.

```
"distance":[
  {
    "weight": 60,
    "unit": "km"
  },
  {
    "weight": 100,
    "unit": "m"
  }
]
```

The java object should look like:

```
[

  {
    "km": 60
  },
  {
    "m": 100
  }
]
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here I have found two issues, One, it is not well formed JSON. It should be:

```
{
 "distance":[
   {
     "weight": 60,
     "unit": "km"
   },
   {
     "weight": 100,
     "unit": "m"
   }
 ]
}
```

OR

```
[
  {
    "weight": 60,
    "unit": "km"
  },
  {
    "weight": 100,
    "unit": "m"
  }
]
```

Another is, you did not mention your POJO clearly. You can achieve this response several ways. For simplicity I am assuming simple `Map` for it.

However, we need to make this string well formed at first.

```
String jsonStr = "\"distance\":[\n" +
                "  {\n" +
                "    \"weight\": 60,\n" +
                "    \"unit\": \"km\"\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  {\n" +
                "    \"weight\": 100,\n" +
                "    \"unit\": \"m\"\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "]";
jsonStr = jsonStr.substring(jsonStr.indexOf(":") + 1);
```

Create a class:

```
@Data
public class Distance {
    private Double weight;
    private String unit;
}
```

Here I have used lombok for getter and setter.

Parse JSON string to **list** of `Distance`:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Distance> distances = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, new TypeReference<List<Distance>>(){});
```

Now you can convert this list to your desired response. For converting this response to `Map`:

```
Map<String, Double> response = distances.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Distance::getUnit, Distance::getWeight));
```

OR, you can convert it to `List<Pair<String, Double>>` as well:

```
List<Pair<String, Double>> response = new ArrayList<>();
distances.forEach(distance -> {
    response.add(new Pair(distance.getUnit(), distance.getWeight()));
});
```

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved using JSONObject and HashMap

1. Use JSONObject to convert json string into java class object.
2. Loop items inside JSONObject to get distance and unit data.
3. Create HashMap object and put it inside ArrayList.

```java
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws JSONException {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double>> result = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Double>>();

        String jsonStr = "{\n" +
                "    \"distance\": [\n" +
                "        { \n" +
                "            \"weight\": 60, \n" +
                "            \"unit\": \"km\" \n" +
                "        }, \n" +
                "        { \n" +
                "            \"weight\": 100, \n" +
                "            \"unit\": \"m\" \n" +
                "        } \n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "}";

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        JSONArray distanceArray = json.getJSONArray("distance");

        for(int i = 0; i < distanceArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject distanceItems = distanceArray.getJSONObject(i);
            final String unit = distanceItems.getString("unit");
            final double weight = distanceItems.getDouble("weight");

            result.add(new HashMap<String, Double>() {{
                put(unit, weight);
            }});
        }

        System.out.println(result.toString()); // output [{km=60.0}, {m=100.0}]
    }
}
```